# How to append a line that does not start with '<' to the previous line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, perl, xml

I have a log which contains XML lines. Sample format below:

```
<head>
    <body>
        <line>
asdasd</line>
    </body>
</head>
```

I want to scan the log file and append the lines that do not start with '<' to the previous line. Output would be like below:

```
<head>
    <body>
        <line>asdasd</line>
    </body>
</head>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'print "\n" if /^\s*+</; chomp;' input > output
```

i.e. newline is removed from each line, and it's printed when the next line starts with whitespace followed by a `<`.

To keep the final newline, change `chomp` to `chomp unless eof` or add `END { print "\n" }`

Comment: Listen to @Sobrique: use an xml parser for this. It will help you immensely in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've said this before - but at risk of sounding like a stuck record - DON'T use regular expressions to parse XML. It's brittle and prone to breaking. I would ask first though - why are you trying to do what you're doing? Because it should be irrelevant when working with your XML.

Instead use a parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parsefile('your_file.xml');

foreach my $elt ( $twig->get_xpath('//#PCDATA') ) {
    $elt->set_text( $elt->trimmed_text );
}

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig->print;
```

This does what you want... but if you're actually working with the XML normally, that `trimmed_text` method probably removes the need for this processing anyway.

Comment: I can't vote today anymore, but I wanted to say thet this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Almost standard sed procedure

```
sed '$!N;s/\n\(\s*[^<[:blank:]]\)/\1/;P;D' log.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the XPath function `normalize-space` to remove the initial newline of the `/head/body/line` node:

```bash
xmlstarlet edit --update '/head/body/line' --expr 'normalize-space(text())' file.xml
```

Or, using abbreviated names:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed -u '/head/body/line' -x 'normalize-space(text())' file.xml
```

The output, given the input in the question, would be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<head>
  <body>
    <line>asdasd</line>
  </body>
</head>
```

Use `//line` in place of the full path from the root node if you want to affect all `line` nodes in your input document.

Add `-O` or `--omit-decl` after `edit` or `ed` to discard the `<?xml ...>` declaration at the start of the resulting document.